# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que git push suba los cambios a dos remotos?

Tags: git, git-push

Tengo un repositorio con dos remotos... uno en GitHub (público) y otro en un servidor privado. En GitHub quiero que siempre esté disponible y actualizada la branch `master`. En mi servidor privado quiero trabajar tranquilo que siempre estén actualizadas todas mis branches y `master` (el trabajo en mis branches es temporal y no quiero que esté visible en GitHub).

¿Cómo puedo hacer que cuando ejecuto `git push` se suba a los dos remotos si estoy en `master` o sólo a mi repositorio privado si estoy en otra branch?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desafortunadamente, `git push` siempre va a hacer push a un solo remoto... peero, como casi siempre, se puede hacer trampa.

Esta solución funciona para MacOS y Linux. Si alguien la adapta a Windows, bienvenid@ :)

Asumo que `origin` apunta al servidor privado y que `github` apunta a... si, GitHub.

La idea es usar [aliases de git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases). Un alias es un comando que nosotros definimos y que puede ser una llamada a otro comando de `git` o una llamada al `shell`.

Un alias no puede sobre escribir un comando ya existente, por lo que se puede hacer que `git pushear` o `git papafrita` haga lo que querés, de esta forma:

```
git config alias.papafrita '!f() { git push origin $@ && if [ `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` == "master" ]; then git push github $@; fi }; f'
```

Esto no es más que código `shell` que hace:

```
push al repo privado
if (estoy en master) {
  push a GitHub
}
```

y funciona! el problema es que te tenés que acordar de hacer `git papafrita` cada vez que querés hacer `git push`. Si quisieras usar `git push` y no otro comando, entonces el truco (saqué la idea de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538774/is-it-possible-to-override-git-command-by-git-alias/24266749#24266749)) es reemplazar `git` por una versión modificada de `git`... lo que hice fué mover el ejecutable `git` y llamarlo `gitreal`, y hacer un script `git.sh` con este contenido:

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND="$1"
if [ "$COMMAND" == "" ]; then
  gitreal
  exit
fi

shift

QUERY="gitreal config --get-regexp ^alias."$COMMAND"alias"
if ( $QUERY > /dev/null ); then
  gitreal "$COMMAND"alias "$@"
else
  gitreal $COMMAND "$@"
fi
```

Esto lo que hace es: cada vez que recibe `git <comando>`, chequear si hay un alias llamado `comandoalias`. Si hay, invoca `gitreal comandoalias`. Si no, llama a `gitreal comando`.

Esta trampa es peligrosa... pero a mí me resulta muy práctica... finalmente, mi alias es:

```
git config alias.pushalias '!f() { if [[ "$@" == "" || "$@" == "-f" ]]; then echo "Pusheando al servidor privado"; git push origin "$@" && if [ `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` == "master" ]; then echo "Pusheando a GitHub"; git push github "$@"; fi else git push "$@"; fi }; f'
```

El primer `if` está chequeando que se trate de un `git push` o un `git push -f`... si no (por ejemplo, en el caso de un `git push origin`), que no sobrescriba nada de lo que está haciendo.

Otro beneficio de esta solución es que los aliases pueden ser por repositorio... entonces, podés tener este comportamiento en algunos repositorios o el `git push` por defecto en otro.

Answer (score 0):

Puede hacer dos mandos, uno por cada remotos:

```
$ git push github master
$ git push privado --all
```

Nota que asumo que el remoto de GitHub se llama `github` y el remoto privado se llama `privado`. Puede sustituir estes nombres según sea apropiado.

Comment: la pregunta es justamente como *no* hacer dos comandos :)